# How I can calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{n}{3^n}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For more than one series of any search function known not seem to find the sum of this series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{n}{3^n}}$$
I've found that converges with the quotient criterion.

Could you give me some suggestions for finding the sum of this series?
Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be one of the most popular questions on MSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

If $|a|<1$,$$a\sum_{0\le n<\infty}r^n=\frac a{1-r}$$ ([Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula))

Differentiate wrt $r$

Answer (score 1):

Since $0<a= \frac{1}{3}<1$ the function $a^n$ converges uniformly, so you can interchange differentiation/integration and summation. Rewrite the expression as 
$$
a\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{da^k}{da}=a \cdot \frac{d}{da}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k
$$
Can you  handle from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{3^n}$, so $3T=3+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{3^{n-1}}=3+T$, and $T=3/2$.

Now let $S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac n{3^n}$. So $$S/3=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1-1}{3^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{3^{n+1}}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}=(S-0)-(T-1),$$ and 
 $$ S=\frac34. $$

(If needed, the manipulations with infinite series can be easily formalized by replacing them with manipulations with partial sums, and taking limits.)