# Determine the value of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n (-\frac{4}{9})^n x^{2n-1}$

I think I have to simplify it to have a cosinus and something else. I tried a few times but I just cant get it to: something + or * $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

Answer (score 1):

For the first, use [How I can calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{n}{3^n}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591285/how-i-can-calculate-sum-n-0-infty-fracn3n)

Observe  that  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n \left(-\frac49\right)^n x^{2n-1}=-\frac{4x}9\cdot\frac2x\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \left(-\frac{4x}9\right)^{n-1}$$

Check for the [convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Common_ratio)  of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{4x}9\right)^n$

For the second   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(ix)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Now from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) defintion $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$\implies e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\ \ \ \ (2)$$

Check $(1)+(2)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it's the derivative of a geometric series.